# Parse CDATA with tag inside, using XMLReader PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xmlreader, cdata

I would need to parse an XML file which contains a CDATA tag. Inside this tag, there is another tag that I want to get. How can I achieve this by using XMLReader?

Example:

```
<glz:Param name="TITLE">
       <![CDATA[Yellow <http://www.yellow.it>]]>
</glz:Param>
```

How can I get the whole info `Yellow <http://www.yellow.it>`? I can only get 'Yellow'.

This is my code:

```
// load file, create a reader variable, etc.
if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::CDATA)
{
   echo $reader->value;
}
```

Comment: are you echo'ing the value in a browser or a shell?

Comment: @Gordon browser

Comment: ok, so the issue is likely that XmlReader correctly fetches the entire content in the CDATA tag, but your browser inteprets it as html again. Check the page source to see if it contains the a element. If so, try echo htmlentities($reader->value) or send a header with content-type: text/plain

Comment: @Gordon it worked out! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Gordon maybe you should write it as answer instead of comment ... so that I can choose it as best answer :)

Comment: done as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments:

The issue is likely that XmlReader correctly fetches the entire content in the CDATA tag, but your browser inteprets it as html again. Check the page source to see if it contains the a element. If so, try

```
echo htmlentities($reader->value);
```

or send a header with content-type: text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by string search. As you can see, String "http://www.yellow.it]]>"is not XML so that you can not parse it using XMLReader. 
Please search string on it. 
For example, you can split the string as "http:" and you can get 2 sub strings. 
From second String, you can get the full link without ">]]>".

Hope it will be helpful.